# Find out how a file was encoded

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have an accounting program from the 1990s called ocl, the program no longer runs correctly and I want to extract the data, when opening the files in sublime text it gives me a long file   like the following

```
393d 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 5072 6576
696f 7573 2054 7261 6e73 2020 2020 2020
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
2020 2035 3430 322e 3235 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

My question is does anyone have any idea what this is or how to go about decoding it? 
I'd be grateful for any ideas

Comment: Try [ASCII hex](http://www.asciitable.com/) - I can see the word 'Previous' spelled out by 50, 72, 65, 76...

Answer (score 0):

Try reading it as text, i.e. ASCII. If you open it in a text editor or hex editor you'll see some readable parts. Notice that `20` is the hex ASCII value for space `' '`. The section you posted decodes to this:

```
9=          Previous Trans                         5402.25
```

This is followed by a series of null (`00`) bytes.

Comment: The hex zero's could indicate a fixed width file or some sort of indexed file. More data would be useful.